# How to give gradient to CircleAvatar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to give a gradient color to `CircleAvatar();` widget in flutter ?

Comment: instead of `CircleAvatar.backgroundColor`? no, there is no way

Comment: @pskink there has to be a way !!

Comment: I don't think it's possible with CircleAvatar. Mimic the behaviour using a Container with circular shape.

Comment: *"there has to be a way !!"* - how? this is a constructor: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar/CircleAvatar.html - there is no any "gradient" parameter

Comment: i was able to achieve the functionality by adding Container as a child and giving gradient properties to the container's box decoration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the functionality I was looking for by using a **Container** as child of **CircleAvatar** and giving **gradient** properties to the **Container**.

```
 CircleAvatar(
        radius: 40,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                color1,
                color2,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                          color1,
                          color2,
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  end: Alignment.topRight
                  )
              ),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text(
                        'MS',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white
                        )
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
              )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wrap `CircleAvatar` with a `Container` and give **shape** and **gradient colors** to `Container` and **transparent color** to `CircleAvatar`.

```dart
child: Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
    colors: [Colors.red, Colors.orange]),
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    radius: 45,
  ),
),
```